# How to automatically turn on WiFi hotspot when the airplane mode is disabled?

Tags: wifi-hotspot, airplane-mode

How can I configure my wifi hotspot so that it is automatically turned on when the airplane mode is disabled?

I use a Google Pixel 6 with Android 12.

Comment: Have you tried using an automation app for this, such as Macrodroid, Tasker, Automate, etc?

Answer (score 1):

One can use MacroDroid:

[image]

Potential problem:

[image] [image]